# CGAL Slicer : How to perform a mesh cut?

Tags: c++, cgal, clip

I'd like to perform the following action using CGAL : 
Intersect a surface mesh; the cut mesh; with another surface mesh; the cutted mesh; to divide the cutted mesh in 2 different meshes.

To do so I use the [CGAL Mesh Slicer](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__mesh__slicer.html) which gives me a set of polylines. Unfortunately, the slicer doesn't provide the information of which face of the cutted mesh each polyline belongs to. Moreover it effectively perfom the slicer action.
How can I retrieve this information ?

I need this information to perform the subdivision of the cutted mesh along the polylines, then the division in 2 separate meshes.

In my context the cut mesh is a surface mesh like this : 
[image: Cut Mesh]

Here is the cut mesh + the cutted mesh : 
[image]

In my code, I generate a Plane from each faces of the cut mesh and perform a slice operation with the cutted mesh.

Here is my code :

```
    //Import off files and instantiate meshes
    const char* filename1 = "test.off";
    const char* filename2 = "cutMesh2.off";
    std::ifstream input(filename1);
    Mesh cuttedMesh, cutMesh;
    if (!input || !(input >> cuttedMesh))
    {
        std::cerr << "First mesh is not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    input.close();
    input.open(filename2);
    if (!input || !(input >> cutMesh))
    {
        std::cerr << "Second mesh is not a valid off file." << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    input.close();
    // AABB Slicer constructor from the cutted mesh
    AABB_tree tree(edges(cuttedMesh).first, edges(cuttedMesh).second, cuttedMesh);
    tree.accelerate_distance_queries();
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_slicer<Mesh, K> slicer_aabb(cuttedMesh, tree);

    std::cout << cutMesh.num_vertices()<< std::endl;
    // For each face of the cut mesh
    BOOST_FOREACH(face_descriptor f, faces(cutMesh))
    {
        std::cout << "Face " << f << std::endl;
        Point points [3];
        int i = 0;
        //for each point of the current face
        BOOST_FOREACH(vertex_descriptor v, CGAL::vertices_around_face(cutMesh.halfedge(f), cutMesh))
        {
            points[i]= cutMesh.point(v);
            ++i;
        }
        Polylines polylines;
        // Perform the slice between the current face of the cut mesh and the cutted mesh
        slicer_aabb(K::Plane_3(points[0],points[1],points[2]), std::back_inserter(polylines));
        std::cout << "the slicer intersects " << polylines.size() << " polylines" << std::endl;

        //for each polyline computed by this face of the cutmesh
        BOOST_FOREACH(Polyline_type polyline,polylines)
        {
            std::cout << "Polyline : " << polyline.size() << " points"<< std::endl;

            BOOST_FOREACH(Point point, polyline)
            {
                std::cout << "Point : " << point << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        polylines.clear();
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try using the non-documented `clip()` function located in `Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/internal/clip.h`

Comment: Hi @sloriot, thanks for you answer. Apparently the clip() function isn't working as expected. I'm trying to perform this cut : [link](https://imgur.com/a/iTccj), but i get this result : [link](https://imgur.com/a/wy9Pj). As you can see the top part of the lantern disappeared... Here are the files I use : [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AmohQtwadi_ThL1dtl15EbG42QpbsQ)

Comment: Simply reverse the orientation of the plane clipper to keep the other part.

Comment: Yes this is what i do to get the bottom part of the lantern. But when dealing the top part (see previously sent screen captures), I am loosing a part of the object that is not supposed to disappear : [Part disappearing (red drawing)](https://imgur.com/4TVeOId), [Expected cut action](https://imgur.com/a/iTccj), [Result after clip()](https://imgur.com/a/wy9Pj). Thank you for you help

Comment: Sorry I get back late to the issue. My guess is that you used the overload that is taking a mesh as clipper. That clipper mesh is expected to be closed in case all connected components are not intersected by that mesh. If you use the plane overload instead, you should get the expected result.

Comment: No problem, thank you for your answer. It appears that my problem was related to an unclean mesh (the cutted mesh). Therefore the operator was not acting as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the post has been proposed by **sloriot** :

> Try using the non-documented clip() function located in Polygon_mesh_processing/include/CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing‌​/internal/clip.h